# Definition of conformal flatness

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance

I was trying to prove that the Ricci scalar $R$ is not invariant under conformal transformations and when we talk about conformal transformations we have the relation:

$$ \hat g_{\mu\nu} = \Omega(x) \eta_{\mu\nu}$$

Is this always the case or can we have some other metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ instead of $ \eta_{\mu\nu}$? I was thinking about this because its a lot easier if the metric is $ \eta_{\mu\nu}$, when computing the Christoffel symbols we can just take them out of the derivatives since all the elements of $ \eta_{\mu\nu}$ are constants.

Comment: The formula for  transformation of $R$ can be found here on page 13 http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/seven.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of Minkowski metric tensor $ \eta_{\mu \nu}$ means, that you are considering the particular class of the metrics, related to the $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ by conformal factor $\Omega(x)$. In general case, one cannot obtain the given metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ from Minkowski metric by a conformal transformation.

However, if you are speaking in the context of string theory, one also has a *differomorphism* invariance, such that the initial metric can be brought to the form, $\Omega(x) \eta_{\mu \nu}$ by a suitable reparametrisation - it is in fact *fixing of gauge*.

Non-invariance of the Ricci curvature $R$ under the conformal transformations can be established readily due to the fact, that $R$ involves two derivatives and has a mass dimension of two. Hence, the rescaling with the constant factor $\lambda$ is bound to produce a factor $\lambda^2$.

However, if you are interested in the exact equation how does the $R$ transform - there would be a certain derivation. Assumption of the conformally equivalent to Minkowski metric simplifies it significantly.

Comment: A derivation of the transformation of the Ricci scalar under conformal transformations, along with the Ricci tensor, can be found in one of the appendices of Wald's *General Relativity*.  (I don't have my copy here in the office, otherwise I'd give you an exact section.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It´s in appendix D I believe, but they use $ \hat g_{\mu\nu} = \Omega^{-2} (x) g_{\mu\nu}$ I was trying for the transformation: $\hat g_{\mu\nu} = e^{2 \sigma (x)} g_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: @MicrosoftBruh:  Just drop in $\Omega = e^{2 \sigma}$ and apply the chain rule, then.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Will do so, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is just one flat metric, if you use spherical coordinates $(u^0,u^1,u^2,u^3) = (t,r,\theta,\phi)$ in Minkowski space you have:

$$\text{d}s^2 = \hat{g}_{\mu\nu} \text{d}u^\mu \text{d}u^\nu = -\text{d}t^2 + \text{d}r^2 + r^2\text{d}\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta\text{d}\phi^2$$

This metric has a zero Riemann tensor: $\text{Rm}(\hat{g}) = (R_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}) = 0$, so every metric of the form:

$$\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu} = \Omega(t,r,\theta,\phi)\ \hat{g}_{\mu\nu}$$

will be "conformally flat" (i.e. its Weyl tensor will be zero).